# Compatibility between amsmath and exscale

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, incompatibility, delimiters

Both the [`amsmath`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) package and the [`exscale`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/exscale.pdf) package define the delimiter macros `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` and `\Bigg` based on the internal macro `\bBigg@`. However, as the following minimal example reveals the `amsmath` and `exscale` versions of `\bBigg@` have a different meaning:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\show\big
%% > \big=\long macro:
%% ->\bBigg@ \@ne .

\csshow{bBigg@}
%% > \bBigg@=macro:
%% #1#2->{\@mathmeasure \z@ {\nulldelimiterspace \z@ }{\left #2\vcenter to#1\big@size {}\right .}\box \z@ }.

\usepackage{exscale}

\show\big
%% > \big=macro:
%% ->\bBigg@ \@ne .

\csshow{bBigg@}
%% > \bBigg@=macro:
%% #1#2->{\hbox {$\left #2\vcenter to#1\big@size {}\right .\n@space $}}.

\begin{document}

\noindent
\Huge \(\big(\sum_{i=1}^{N}i\big)\)

\end{document}
```

Does this mean that I might get different results, depending on whether the `amsmath` package is loaded before or after the `exscale` package? Or are the two versions of `\bBigg@` interchangeable so that the package loading order essentially doesn’t matter?

Comment: I'd say that you should use the `amsmath` definition, so load `exscale` before it. My impression is that the definition by `exscale` was inspired by that in `amsmath` but of course without `\@mathmeasure` that is important during work on alignments (and not only there).

Comment: @egreg: So, in essence, this means that the `exscale` package should probably define `\bBigg@` only if the `amsmath` package has not been loaded yet.

Comment: Neither package seems to be aware of the other, at least no mention of each other in their source or documentation than I could `grep`. egreg has provided what's probably a suitable answer in his comment, though I can't say I understand the difference between the two definitions to know how different things might look or how things might work. You might like to contact the package maintainers for both to get their input, and ask to them "play nicely" together or document the interaction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three examples

### Without any package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
$\sum_\sum$

\Huge$\sum_\sum$
\end{document}
```

[image]

### With `exscale`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{exscale}
\begin{document}
$\sum_\sum$

\Huge$\sum_\sum$
\end{document}
```

[image]

### With `amsmath`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\sum_\sum$

\Huge$\sum_\sum$
\end{document}
```

[image]

### With `exscale` and `amsmath`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{exscale,amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\sum_\sum$

\Huge$\sum_\sum$
\end{document}
```

[image]

### With `amsmath` and without `lmodern`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\sum_\sum$

\Huge$\sum_\sum$
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Conclusions

The `lmodern` family has the extension symbol font in only one size, namely `lmex10`. With `amsmath` and the standard Computer Modern fonts, the "scaled" fonts `cmex7` and `cmex5` will be used, but of course this isn't possible if `lmodern` is loaded.

The definition of `\bBigg@` given in `exscale` is obviously modelled on that by `amsmath`, but lacks its infrastructure, so it falls back to the standard LaTeX method.

If `exscale` is necessary because Latin Modern fonts are preferred, then `exscale` should be loaded *before* `amsmath`, so that the definition of `\bBigg@` is eventually given by the latter.

Comment: Thanks! Moreover, it seems that the `exscale` package should also be loaded before the `amsfonts` package since both packages declare a font shape for the `cmex` family.