# Strange behavior with lmodern package

Tags: fonts, latin-modern

I am making an A0 poster using the `lmodern` package, which has a strange influence on formula formatting.

Removing this package makes everything work well, but I would like to know what I have done wrong.

With `lmodern` package :

[image]

Without `lmodern` package :

[image]

Here is the corresponding code.

```
\documentclass[landscape,30pt]{sciposter}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsrefs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\begin{document}

$$\int_0^\infty \sqrt{\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}}dt$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\int` sign does not have a bigger version. If you use some other package for math fonts, like `euler` or `mathpazo` for example, it works. Interesting.

Comment: The clash seem to happen between `sciposter` and `lmodern`. Also, note that your example isn't minimal: `babel` and the `ams` packages are not required to reproduce the bug. Similarly, the options you provide for `sciposter` can and should be omitted too.

Comment: `\usepackage{exscale}` after `\usepackage{lmodern}` should fix it. See [Compatibility between amsmath and exscale](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80088)

Comment: you can also do `\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}`.

Comment: On the basis of egreg's comment, the problem is a dupe