# Should one always use exscale when using lmodern?

Tags: math-mode, packages

At the moment I only use summation signs with symbols which have a normal high and also no summation signs in subscripts. Due to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82446/45570) post is it correct that I should always use the exscale package when using the lmodern fonts? And is it correct that the package will load the `CMEX10`font for the summation signs?

Comment: Much as it pains me to say you should do as egreg says, I think yes is probably the right answer (but the font is lmex10 not cmex10 if you are using lmodern)

Comment: The `lmex10` and `cmex10` fonts are quite the same, so using the latter will not be distinguishable; if you happen to use `\sum` in a section title you'll notice a big difference between using `exscale` or not.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I checked the fonts in Acrobat under the fonts listing and there it shows me CMEX10, maybe this is lmex10, but I don't find any hint about lmex10 in my document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not only in using `\sum` in subscripts, as the following example shows. The version without `exscale` has a clearly wrong output.

### Without `exscale`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\textheight=2cm % just for the example

\begin{document}
Some text\footnote{Because $\sum_{k=1}^{n}=n(n+1)/2$.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### With `exscale`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{exscale}

\textheight=2cm % just for the example

\begin{document}
Some text\footnote{Because $\sum_{k=1}^{n}=n(n+1)/2$.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing out it has wrong output. It is a bit strange that lmodern without an additional package is missing the function to scale the sum sign and that this issue wasn't already fixed.